# How to keep value of String after clicking Submit button in .jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, html, string, jsp

I have a problem, that after clicking submit button I'm loosing what is already in my textToConsole variable. After submitting, I only have "hello" in it.  How can I prevent from losing the text: "world!"?

```
<% String textToConsole = "hello"; %>

<form method="POST">
        <div align="center">
            <select name="chooseComboBox" id="chooseComboBox" size="3">
               <option>Option 1</option>
               <option>Option 2</option>
               <option>Option 3</option>
               <option>Option 4</option>
            </select>
            
            <h2 align="center">Enter the range of dates: </h2>
            
            <label>Od:</label>
            <input type="date" name="inputFrom"
               value="2020-01-01"
               min="2000-01-01" max="2022-12-31">
            
            <br><br>
            <label for="inputTo">Do:</label>
            <input type="date" name="inputTo"
               value="2021-01-01"
               min="2000-01-01" max="2022-12-31">
        
            <br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" style="font-size: 20px;" value="Wyeksportuj do pliku">
            </div>
    </form>

    String chooseComboBox = request.getParameter("chooseComboBox");

    if(chooseComboBox != null) {
          textToConsole += "world!";
    }


    <div align="center" id="logConsole">
        <% out.print(textToConsole); %>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can store that value inside httpsession and get it from there .

Comment: @Swati Thanks a lot! Add this as an answer and I will mark this as best solution ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, store that value inside Httpsession and get it from there!